# Tomcat serving pages from temp directory instead of webapps directory

Tags: tomcat, springframework

I have an Apache Tomcat (Spring) application deployed inside a Docker container. Host is Centos 7, container is Debian 9.

In the past, I have run this application without any problems outside of Docker.

I deploy the application how I always have, by copying the required files into `${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/appname/`. The application is loaded fine, however a copy of the application is moved automatically to `${CATALINA_HOME}/temp/3-appname/`.

I didn't think this would be a problem, but noticed that if I change a JSP page in `${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/appname/`, nothing happens. If I change it in the temp directory, the change is shown.

In my Spring application, a call to `ServletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF")` results in the WEB-INF directory in the temp directory.

I'm assuming the problem is some context configuration somewhere, but I am not sure where to set it, as I have not had to set this in the past.

How can I stop the application from being served out of the temp directory, rather than the webapps directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a side-effect of something I did to fix a bug:

`${CATLINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml` had `antiResourceLocking="true"` in the `<Context>` element. This results in multiple copies of the webapp being served from the temp directory.